# showing categories in a dropdown

Tags: ee2, categories

One of my category groups is rather big ( 100+ categories ) and the tree-structure to show categories just doesn't cut it anymore. It's too long and confusing.

So I would like to display my categories in a dropdown on the publish page.
**Something very similar to this: [WB Category Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select), but without having to use a custom field to display and store the categories.**

I really want to use the native categories because of 2 reasons:

1. All of my entries are allready assigned to their categories, and I don't want to redo this for 1000+ entries in 100+ different categories
2. I'm working with [GWCode categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) to display everything on the front-end, and that add-on only works with the native categories

That's why WB category select is out of the question.

So how do I do this, **can I build an add-on to affect the way categories are being outputted in the back-end** ?

Also, the categories have multiple levels of subcategories, but they don't require multiple selections, so a drop-down should be sufficient ( doesn't have to be a multi-select )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an add-on called Lonely Cat http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lonely-cat that may be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: yep, using that now. The only problem is that it doesn't automatically select the category I've already assigned to my entry prior to installing this add-on. Any idea how I can fix this, without having to resort to re-setting all my categories manually ?   -  http://cl.ly/image/3Z2E2C1z380S

Comment: bummer. Maybe get in touch with the developer?

Comment: already did that, hoping it won't take too long to get a reply :)